# VBA - Word 2007 - Subscript out of range (error 9)

Tags: vba, vbscript, range, subscript

I don't know what's causing this. 
I've created a template with a lot of macro code in it. And I've used the Custom UI EDitor for Office 2007 applications to create a custom Tab in the Ribbon interface. In this tab I've got this button which is supposed to open a userform. The XML code for the button is this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="CustomForm" label="CustomForm">
                <group id="customuserdata" label="Custom Userdata">
                    <button id="openForm" label="Open userform" imageMso="OpenForm" size="large" onAction="openForm" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

And in the same Template I've got a Public Sub named `openForm` and it this I just run `myForm.Show`. It's in this sub that the error occurs "Run-Time error '9'. SubScript out of range". What could cause this?

The exact code of the Sub I'm trying to call is this:

```
Public Sub openForm(control As IRibbonControl)
    FormAltData.Show ' This is where the debugger stops at'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by an Array I believe. I tried to access an array before it was even declared ^^ My bad :)